# What would consider a "boring or unnecessary" scene?

Tags: scene, child-characters, prose-style

In a chapter I'm currently writing is of an ostracized boy stumbling in a forest and being amazed with childlike-wonder. From the feel of the grass on his bare feet to the flora and fauna around.

In a short summary: It'll just be a boy reacting to a part of mother nature, playing and discovering this unfamiliar terrain, feeling liberated and finally founding a safe haven for him to seek.

Throw in some flowery language here and there etc.

But, I do wonder that will it be "boring" for readers if a chapter is just this?

*Is* a scene featuring a lone character reflecting or experiencing a "mundane" day unnecessary?

Comment: Write it deeply in his POV.  use the flowery language only if HE would use it.  And particularly notice only what he would notice.

Answer (score 4):

A peaceful, mundane scene isn't necessarily boring or unnecessary. It depends on how it fits in the rest of the narrative.

I think most typically, I'd expect a scene like that to function as a contrast for conflict that comes before or after. Or to build up tension, with the implicit promise that this moment of peace will be torn apart.

But even on its own, if you do a good job to bring across the wonder and freedom the boy feels, then I think readers could enjoy that.

Answer (score 3):

The body of your question doesn't quite fit with the subject line. A boring and unnecessary scene or chapter is one that doesn't advance the story, build the character, establish that things are at risk or gained or lost, and so.  BUt, that isn't want you seem to want to know about.

Boring is just another word for unengaged.

Readers become engaged with a story when they try to anticipate where the story going next. This isn't just about plot points and character arcs, but even extends to the sentence level of a story.

I think in the scene or chapter you are describing there won't be external dangers or internal conflicts, which are the normal subjects that story telling us to get readers engaged.

In your case, it will down to the character's reactions and the character's actions and the skill of the narrative to that will establish engagement through setting and emotion.

This is a difficult thing to achieve, but it can be done, I think.

While you can create some interest with strong prose describing your 40 Acre Woods, that won't carry a story for more than a few paragraphs.  Describing a child at play as they move from inhibited or cautious by a new place to feeling  safe and free and joyous seems like a good tract to follow.  Because I think if gives you the potential to express the transformation of the child using their own point of view.  The narrator can also step in at times and describe how child physically moves, how its hesitancy manifests in the exploration at the start and how unhestitent the child is at the end of the scene.  Similarly, you can use transitions from cautious to joyous, and other  dimension you feel apply.

Lastly, these kinds of moments are terrific places to use cumulative sentences    because they can evoke the kind of mental processes that put the reader in the frame of mind to draw upon their own experience and imagination to anticipate what is happening in the story.